# Changing verbatim input in beamer slide

Tags: beamer, verbatim

I am trying to produce a presentation where code for a pair of arrays appear in the same position of a beamer slide.

I tried something like this (with different combinations and braces) and did not work.

```
\begin{verbatim}\only<1>

     V1 V2 V3 V4
[1,]  0  1  1  0
[2,]  1  0  1  0
[3,]  1  1  0  0
[4,]  0  0  0  0


\only<2>

     V1 V2 V3 V4
[1,]  0  1  0  0
[2,]  1  0  1  0
[3,]  0  0  0  0
[4,]  0  0  0  0

\end{verbatim}
```

Appreciate any suggestions.

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`verbatim` material cannot appear in the argument of another command, so the usual approach `\only<1>{\begin{verbatim}...\end{verbatim}}` won't work. The easiest solution is to use the `onlyenv` environment (thanks to **daleif** for [`his comment`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/250958/changing-verbatim-input-in-beamer-slide#comment598001_250966) about this):

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[fragile]
\begin{onlyenv}<1>
\begin{verbatim}
     V1 V2 V3 V4
[1,]  0  1  1  0
[2,]  1  0  1  0
[3,]  1  1  0  0
[4,]  0  0  0  0
\end{verbatim}
\end{onlyenv}
\begin{onlyenv}<2>
\begin{verbatim}
     V1 V2 V3 V4
[1,]  0  1  0  0
[2,]  1  0  1  0
[3,]  0  0  0  0
[4,]  0  0  0  0
\end{verbatim}
\end{onlyenv}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

An animation of the result:

[image]

Comment: Can't it be used inside the `onlyenv` environment?

Comment: @daleif Of course! I updated my answer. Thanks.

Comment: I think I got it from Josephs W.s blog http://texdev.net

Comment: Thanks a lot Gonzalo and daleif. It works like a charm...

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the `verbatimbox` package to save the verbatim content into a named LaTeX box prior to the `\only` and then apply `\only` to the box.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{verbatimbox}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[fragile]
\begin{myverbbox}{\onlyA}
     V1 V2 V3 V4
[1,]  0  1  1  0
[2,]  1  0  1  0
[3,]  1  1  0  0
[4,]  0  0  0  0
\end{myverbbox}
\begin{myverbbox}{\onlyB}
     V1 V2 V3 V4
[1,]  0  1  0  0
[2,]  1  0  1  0
[3,]  0  0  0  0
[4,]  0  0  0  0\end{myverbbox}
\only<1>\onlyA
\only<2>\onlyB
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: @Toño That is strange, since I run MikTeX 2.9 and have no problem.  But the good news is that the sty file can be downloaded from http://ctan.org/pkg/verbatimbox.  You can place it in your working directory, or else in MikTeX's default package directory: `C:\Users\StevenSegletes\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex`, where my name is replaced by the appropriate name for your file structure.  Of course, then, you have to update the filename database (FNDB).