# Beamer with columns, verbatim and overlay

Tags: beamer, verbatim, columns, overlays

The following example works fine:

```
\begin{frame}[fragile]
  \begin{columns}
    \column{.5\textwidth}
    \begin{itemize}[<+->]
    \item First
    \item Second
    \end{itemize}
    \column{.5\textwidth}
    \visible<3>{
      Third
      }
  \end{columns}
\end{frame}
```

However, I've tried to set Third as a verbatim text.
With

```
\begin{frame}[fragile]
  \begin{columns}
    \column{.5\textwidth}
    \begin{itemize}[<+->]
    \item First
    \item Second
    \end{itemize}
    \column{.5\textwidth}
    \visible<3>{
\begin{verbatim}
      Third
\end{verbatim}
      }
  \end{columns}
\end{frame}
```

it can't be compiled. I've got an error message:

```
Runaway argument?
  \end{columns}rbatim} \beamer@endinvisible 
! File ended while scanning use of \@xverbatim.
<inserted text> 
\par 
l.17 \end{frame}
```

However, the following is compiling, but it results in summary of four overlays, but it should have only three (overlays two and three are identical):

```
\begin{frame}[fragile]
  \begin{columns}
    \column{.5\textwidth}
    \begin{itemize}[<+->]
    \item First
    \item Second
    \end{itemize}
    \column{.5\textwidth}
    \pause
\begin{verbatim}
      Third
\end{verbatim}
  \end{columns}
\end{frame}
```

Comment: `\begin{onlyenv}<3>
\begin{verbatim}
      Third
\end{verbatim}
      \end{onlyenv}` works (there is probably a duplicate question somewhere, I'll take a look).

Comment: Sort of a mix between https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/250958/changing-verbatim-input-in-beamer-slide and https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/223787/beamer-overlays-with-tikz-nodes-break-verbatim-whitespace-handling/, I guess this one can stay open.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
\begin{frame}[fragile]
  \begin{columns}
    \column{.5\textwidth}
    \begin{itemize}[<+->]
    \item First
    \item Second
    \end{itemize}
    \column{.5\textwidth}
    \begin{visibleenv}<3>
\begin{verbatim}
      Third
\end{verbatim}
    \end{visibleenv}
  \end{columns}
\end{frame}
```